# How can I change URL without render using React Router 6?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, react-router, use-effect

```
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
          <Route path="object" element={<Navigate to="/object/new" />} />
          <Route path="object/:objId" element={<ObjEditor />} />
          <Route path="object/new" element={<ObjEditor />} />
          <Route index element={<Navigate to="/object/new" />} />
        </Route>
```

Using react router, you can navigate to an object with the URL `/object/1234`. The `<ObjEditor>` will fetch data from the DB on render. I would like it so that if you enter an unknown `objId` in the URL, the address will change to `object/new`, without causing a re-render.

I tried calling react router's `navigate("/object/new")` function from the `useEffect` hook, but because the data fetch is async, it navigates away even from an `objId` that does exist in the DB.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: why not navigating inside ObjEditor component, in the fetch callback if the id does not exist?

Comment: @MWO I ended up eventually roughly in that ballpark. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
  const [requestedObj, setRequestedObj] = useState();
  const { objId } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (requestedObj)
      dispatch({ type: Actions.LOAD_OBJECT, obj: requestedObj });
  }, [requestedObj]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;

    const fetchObject = async () => {
      const obj = await db.getObject(objId | 0);

      if (isSubscribed && obj) {
        setRequestedObj(obj);
      }
    };

    fetchObject().catch(() => {
      navigate("/object/new");
    });

    return () => (isSubscribed = false);
  }, [objId, setRequestedObj]);
```

Comment: Did you really intend this bitwise operation `db.getObject(objId | 0)`?

Comment: @DrewReese good question. It converts a number string to an integer. Since my IDs are all natural numbers, I find it a nice shorthand.

Comment: I see, that is a nice trick, though very easy to confuse with the fallback value syntax `db.getObject(objId || 0)` for the case that `objId` is a falsey value. `db.getObject(Number(objId))` would, IMO, be as effective and is more readable.

Comment: @DrewReese I completely agree with you